# Using jQuery Autocomplete without label and value

Tags: php, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

This is my **PHP JSON RESPONSE**

```
data_id: [59, 92, null]
data_type: [null, null, place]
ident: [null, null, b88b0366b9799fc6836db767d91cf733c0a512ee]
image: [b.png,c.png,a.png]
visit: [5, 3, null]
name: [China, Chinua Okeke, <span class="nowrapshit">Just Use "ch"</span>]
```

**JQUERY**(response function)

```
    $(document).on('keyup','.search',function(){
    var q = $(this).val();
            $.post('resource/php/search.php',{
                q : q,
                action : 'search'
            },function(data){
                var data_id = data.data_id,
                    name = data.name,
                    image = data.image,
                    visit = data.visit,
                    ident = data.ident;

        $thisB.autocomplete({
            source : name
        }).data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
            console.log(item);
            return $('<li class="sbSingleUiTokenLister" data_id="'+item.data_id+'"   data_type="'+item.data_type+'" ident_id="'+item.ident+'"></li>' )
                .data('item.autocomplete',item)
                .append('<img src="'+item.image+'" />')
                .append('<span class="name">'+item.name + '</span>')
                .append('<span class="visits">'+ item.visit + '</span>')
                .appendTo(ul);
            };
    },'json');
});
```

But the above piece of code does not works as object `item` contains only `label` and `value`
How can i print this piece of code perfectly ?

Comment: Have you tried `keyup`?

Comment: this is all inside a keyup @Boaz

Comment: So why is the title saying `keydown`? Also, please include the complete relevant part of the code.

Comment: sorry changed the title a stack overflow BUG! @Boaz